# Are variables definined in a required file not available outside?

Tags: php, scope, global

In requiredfile.php I define $a = 5. The in index.php I do this:

```
require_once(requiredfile.php);
echo $a;
```

But it seems that $a is not defined. Why is this?

Comment: That should just work. There must be something else going wrong. Perhaps you have all the errors and warnings hidden and something is going wrong. So it would output an empty page.

Comment: It should work perfectly... require_once is just like copying the code from the other page and pasting in the present file. Your code works perfectly on my machine, mind you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is possible to access global variables the way you do.

So two possibilities come to mind to explain your issue:

1. you declare the variable *not* on global scope, but inside a class or function definition.
2. your `require_once()` command fails (any errors in the log file?) due to the fact that you forgot the quotes around the file name or because the file is not found at that position (check the path!).

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around your filename:

```
require_once('requiredfile.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables defined in an other file are available if you import it (require/include).

Are you sure that your file is correctly imported (no error...) ?

Answer (score 0):

In general you can access the variables declared in the included file.

Please make sure that

1. required the file like this require_once('requiredfile.php');
2. variable is declared not inside any private or protected class
3. The file is included (I think here the file is included because you are getting the error that $a is not defined)
4. Make sure the variable name and make sure it is declared.